# "In almost" vs "Almost in"

Tags: prepositions, word-order, adverbs

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. In almost all cases, ...
> 2. Almost in all cases, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"In almost all cases" sounds better to me, **as *almost* refers to *all***:  "almost all".
It also occurs much more often than the second sentence (21M vs. 137K in Google).

I don't think "almost in all cases" is grammatically incorrect thought.

Answer (score 4):

I think both are technically correct, but the former sounds much better. ["In almost all cases"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22in+almost+all+cases%22) also seems to have more google hits than ["almost in all cases"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22almost+in+all+cases%22).

Answer (score 2):

"In almost all cases", as Bruno said, positions "almost" to refer to "all", and is less ambiguous.

"Almost in all cases" is ambiguous.  Consider the following context:

```
He almost won all his cases.

He won almost all his cases.
```

These two interpretations express very propositions, and would result in very different performance evaluations for the attorney in question.